# Forming a 12 letter string -- not sure why I'm overcounting

Tags: combinatorics

I can't see how this overcounts. I have the solution done by Inclusion-Exclusion principle, but I can't see why mine gives more ways
We would like to form 12 letter strings, made up using the 26 letters of the English alphabet. How many of these strings contain at least one X and at least one Y and at least one Z?
This is what I thought:
Since we want at least one $X,Y,Z$, then choose spots for these letters in
$$\binom{12}3\times 3!$$
ways.
Then, I can just choose letters freely since the criteria is satisfied in $26^{9}$ ways.
So the total is $\binom{12}3\times 3! \times 26^9$.

Comment: e.g. string XXXXYYYYZZZZ is counted more than once.

Answer (score 0):

By designating a particular X, Y, and Z as the ones reserved for X, Y, and Z, respectively, you count each string as many times as X appears, as many times as Y appears, and as many times as Z appears.  Consider the string 
$$ABCDEFXYYZZZ$$
You count it $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6$ times.
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}\color{blue}{Y}Y\color{green}{Z}ZZ$$
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}\color{blue}{Y}YZ\color{green}{Z}Z$$
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}\color{blue}{Y}YZZ\color{green}{Z}$$
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}Y\color{blue}{Y}\color{green}{Z}ZZ$$
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}Y\color{blue}{Y}Z\color{green}{Z}Z$$
$$ABCDEF\color{red}{X}Y\color{blue}{Y}ZZ\color{green}{Z}$$